# Html layout with header and left menu of 100% height

Tags: html, layout

I'm struggling to create a very simple layout of header and 2 column content - left navigation and right content (http://jsfiddle.net/WsQbs/4/).

What I cannot achieve is having menu and content take 100% height of the page (not just window), while having a vertical line (border) between menu and content. The problem is that when positioning content absolutely and any of the 2 columns have enough content, so that scrollbars appear, the background and border of corresponding divs still only take 100% of the window, not full height of the content.

Comment: your `#content-wrapper` won't use the 100% height since the `#header` has 50px height, besides it also has a position with a top different than 0...

Comment: I found solution, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26994674/1096901

Answer (score 0):

the absolute position prevent it from you want. is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/WsQbs/6/

update: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/WsQbs/8/

Comment: No - if you leave just a small amount of content, the divs don't take 100% of the page anymore - http://jsfiddle.net/WsQbs/7/

Comment: the main body should have an actual height. so that divs height can refer it. set the body height to something large value. and it will works, of course this is not a perfect solution, but it can be used. see update.

Comment: This means always having scrollbars, which is not what I need :(